# Sorting List<List<MyType>>

Tags: c#, list, sorting, icomparable

I have 2D a list of "NameValuePair"s that I've been trying to order with no luck so far.

NameValuePair is defined as:

```
public class NameValuePair
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

The list is defined as:

```
List<List<NameValuePair>> outerList = new List<List<NameValuePair>>();
```

Each list in outer list might have different number of items at different indices but each one has a "Date" item for sure.

e.g.

```
List<List<NameValuePair>> outerList = new List<List<NameValuePair>>();
List<NameValuePair> innerList = new List<NameValuePair>();
List<NameValuePair> innerList2 = new List<NameValuePair>();


innerList.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "List1Item1", Value = "someValue" });
innerList.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "List1Item2", Value = "otherValue" });
innerList.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "List1ItemN", Value = "anotherValue" });
innerList.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "Date", Value = "aDateInStringFormat" });
innerList2.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "List2Item1", Value = "myValue" });
innerList2.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "Date", Value = "anotherDateInStringFormat" });
innerList2.Add(new NameValuePair { Name = "List2ItemM", Value = "bestValue" });

outerList.Add(innerList);
outerList.Add(innerList2);
```

I have tried sorting with `outerList.Sort();` and `outerList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Where(y => y.Name == "Date")).ToList();` with no luck so far.

I also tried implementing `IComparable` to my NameValuePair type by overloading `CompareTo()` but couldn't get it working either.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: First of all: your *NameValuePair* basically is just a *Dictionary*. Besides that: when you know that each *NameValuePair* has a *Date* entry, why don't you add a 'Date' property to your object and search by that?

Comment: Each _NameValuePair_ does not have a _Date_ entry. It's rather, each _List<NameValuePair>_ has a _NameValuePair_ with _Name_ "Date"
Sorting inner list doesn't help either. Because what I need to do is sorting each _List<NameValuePair>_ by the Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each inner list has exactly one item with name `Date` and a proper formated date `Value`:

```
var sorted = outerList.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Single(y => y.Name == "Date").Value))
                      .ToList();
```

The `Linq` query takes the `NameValuePair` with the `Name` "Date", converts the `Value` to a `DateTime` object and sorts the outer list by this value.

Anyway you should think about creating a class with a `DateTime` property instead.

Comment: Looks good, but I think he probably wanted `OrderByDescending` (given what he tried in the OP)

Comment: I changed OrderBy to OrderByDescending and worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @uTe1sT I hope your outer list isn't too long though, because this could be EXTREMELY SLOW if it is. Like Flat Eric said, it's much better to create a class with a DateTime property.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It'll be a maximum of 50 items I think. The thing about NameValuePair type is that, it has been defined long before I joined the project and has been used by other teams as well. It'll be kinda though for me to change it at this point. Thx for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but here's a slightly different take which is likely to be more performant.

Firstly, do a single pass of all the lists to extract the date times into a separate sequence:

```
var keys = outerList.Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Single(y => y.Name == "Date").Value));
```

Then use Zip and that DateTime sequence to sort the outer list by that sequence:

```
outerList = outerList.Zip(keys, (pairs, date) => new {Pairs = pairs, Date = date})
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Date)
    .Select(item => item.Pairs)
    .ToList();
```

This avoid multiple calls to `IEnumerable.Single()` and DateTime parsing whenever two elements are compared during the sorting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for additional comment. I'll keep it in mind just in case I have performance issues.